# How to find device type whether is it a computer or mobile in vb.net with SQL Server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a project in which I need to know the device type (Computer or Mobile). I have searched everywhere but cannot find the answer.

Comment: Maybe looking at trying to find the screen size of the device that's currently running the app/site? Do you have code to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Googling "javascript get device type" returnet a lot of results; have you tried any of them?

Comment: see if this helps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149688.aspx

Comment: Is this an asp.net project or windows desktop app? That could make a difference on how you approach this and what options are available to you. If you're looking at querying a device based off an ip address, you may need to look into WMI. If you want to do device detection of the local device a web page is running on that's a different approach. Please explain the scenario and re ask your question clearly. There are too many unknowns wrt your question here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using below function to check is it mobile browser or not? otherwise it's always computer browser.

```
Public Shared Function isMobileBrowser() As Boolean
    'GETS THE CURRENT USER CONTEXT
    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

    'FIRST TRY BUILT IN ASP.NT CHECK
    If context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice Then
        Return True
    End If
    'THEN TRY CHECKING FOR THE HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE HEADER
    If context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE") IsNot Nothing Then
        Return True
    End If
    'THEN TRY CHECKING THAT HTTP_ACCEPT EXISTS AND CONTAINS WAP
    If context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT") IsNot Nothing AndAlso context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT").ToLower().Contains("wap") Then
        Return True
    End If
    'AND FINALLY CHECK THE HTTP_USER_AGENT 
    'HEADER VARIABLE FOR ANY ONE OF THE FOLLOWING
    If context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT") IsNot Nothing Then
        'Create a list of all mobile types
        Dim mobiles As String() = {"midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", _
        "palmsource", "240x320", "opwv", "chtml", "pda", "windows ce", _
        "mmp/", "blackberry", "mib/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", _
        "hand", "mobi", "phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio", _
        "SIE-", "SEC-", "samsung", "HTC", "mot-", "mitsu", _
        "sagem", "sony", "alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx", _
        "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", _
        "sch", "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", _
        "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", _
        "voda", "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", _
        "gradi", "jb", "dddi", "moto", "iphone"}
        ' "NEC", 
        'Loop through each item in the list created above 
        'and check if the header contains that text
        For Each s As String In mobiles
            If context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```